# Выводится только первая запись таблицы,а не все

Tags: php, mysql

Такая ситуация , есть функция выборки статей из базы данных

```
public function getInformation(){
                $link = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM article");
                $row = $link->fetch_assoc();
                $this->con->close();
                return $row;
            }
```

При выводе значение этой функции , выводится только первая запись таблицы , а должны все

```
    $db = new Database ;
    $db->connect();
    print_r($db->getInformation()) ;
```

Comment: Так выводятся все - а вот Вы берёте из всех только первую, на чём и успокаиваетесь.

Comment: а вот здесь,можете поподобнее объяснить ?

Comment: можно. ЛЮБОЙ пример использования функции fetch_assoc, В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ приведённый в документации, показывает, как её использовать для получения нескольких строк.

Comment: вы можете объяснить, какое отношение к этому вопросу имеют метки HTML и яваскрипт?